# C# SQL: How can I increment an integer value in a database by one on multiple records?

Tags: c#, sql

I am looking for the best way to update the value I store on the following structure:

Table: **Pages**

Fields:

1. id (int)
2. bookid (int)
3. pageorder (int)
4. filename (string/varchar)

So I have the book order and a page number. I need to insert a page before the page number I have, lets say 25, and update all the other pages to have 1 added to their pageorder value.

Can I do this without pulling a list and cycling threw it running updates, or is that the best way to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
declare @newpage int
set @newpage = 25
update pages set pageorder = pageorder +1 where pageorder >= @newpage and bookid = @bookid
```

something like that?

Comment: Looks like it is working, thanks a million! Will accept when I can.

Comment: Probably want to filter by bookid, otherwise that's going to end badly.

Comment: Yes I only gave a very rough prototype - you definitely want to add filtering so you don't update EVERY book.

Comment: Ya I figured, but your answer gave me the bit of information that somehow slipped out of my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly with SQL, Like this

```
update pages 
set pageorder = pageorder + 1
where bookid=@bookid
and pageorder >= @pageorder;

insert into Pages
(id,bookid,pageorder,filename)
values
(@id,@bookid,@pageorder,@filename);
```

Comment: You want to be careful to do your update first, otherwise you'll end up with two page 25's after the insert that'll both become page 26 after the update.

Comment: Not sure its worthy to downvote. The accepted answer doesnt even filter by bookId :p That can end up even worse.

Comment: I'm assuming the downvote is because initially because I had the insert first.  The funny part is that I actually made a mental note to do the update first, then proceeded to type it wrong.  Oh well, fixed now.